# Running Unity Build through Command line

Tags: unity, linux

I recently developed a game in unity and would like to build it to a standalone application using the command line. Is there a way to do that?

Specifically, without opening the Unity Editor how can I use the command line to build my project to a standalone application?

I am using Linux.

Comment: This question [is already answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081576/how-can-i-compile-a-unity3d-game-project-from-command-line-into-webgl). The command line example is for Windows, but it should work in a very similar way on Linux.

Comment: This is also [explained in the Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html), which is the very first search result for "unity command-line," and already [answered for the Mac case in past Q&A here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/62623/39518), so I feel this question does not demonstrate research effort in its current form. Please show us that you've done a basic search, read the relevant documentation, and made an effort to implement this feature for your case. If the instructions provided for Mac and Windows don't work for you on Linux, explain how.